# ereg_replace equivalent in C#

Tags: c#, pattern-matching, ereg-replace

I need to know how can we use  $`no = ereg_replace(" .*", "", $command[$i]);` equivalent in c#, I am very newbie in pattern matching, can anyone please let me know the examples of pattern matching in c#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can use Regex.

In this example, we want to delete all of HTML tags that we have in string.

```
string newDescription = Regex.Replace("hello how are <b>you</b>", "<[^>]*>", string.Empty);
```

newDescription now have "hello how are you"

Comment: Good grief, I think that would be overkill.  `String.Replace` should do the trick a lot easier.

Comment: He ask for a pattern, if is a simple pattern ok, he should be use replace.

Comment: @mpacheco can you please tell me what this function done? ereg_replace(" .*", "",...

Comment: Do you mean, do you want delete all of "extensions" in string?
Examnple string1.com string2.es string3.org the result should be string1 string2 string3?